# Plotly html export with dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly, plotly-python

I am using plotly go to create interactive charts, and then I am exporting them to html, so I can work with them without python. But the problem is, where I want to see a dataframe, or work with it (for instance in excel). Is there some way, to open dataframe from html plotly export ?

Yes, align with plotly html file I can also export the current dataframe, but I was hoping to have just 1 file.

Thank you

Sample code

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go


df=pd.DataFrame({'Value1': [1,4,8.2,3,7,10.2], 'Value2': [4,9,5,2.2,6.5,15]})
date = pd.date_range('2022-01-25', periods=6, freq='H')
date=pd.DataFrame(date,columns=['Date'])
df=pd.concat([date,df], axis=1)
print(df)

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df["Date"],y=df["Value1"],name="Value1"))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df["Date"],y=df["Value2"],name="Value2"))
fig.update_layout(hovermode="x unified")
fig.update_layout(
    title="Test",
    xaxis_title="Time",
    yaxis_title="Values [-]",
    legend=dict(
    yanchor="top",
    y=0.99,
    xanchor="left",
    x=0.01))
#fig.show()
fig.write_html("test.html")
```

I am also adding prntscrn from plotly_html export to show, from which file I would like to access data

[image: Plotly export]

Comment: can you clarify what you want with some screenshots and code? do you want the dataframe to be editable in the html file itself?

Comment: Done :) No, it doesnt have to be editable, but it will be good if df can be copied to excel.